# How do I package with fyne for macOS? -clang argument unused error

Tags: go, packaging, fyne

I installed the 64bit version of llvm with https://llvm.org/builds/ , and checked `add to path` on the installer. Although it seems to have installed clang, I still get an error:

```
fyne package -os darwin
# runtime/cgo
clang: error: argument unused during compilation: '-arch x86_64' [-Werror,-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: error: argument unused during compilation: '-mmacosx-version-min=10.11' [-Werror,-Wunused-command-line-argument]

error building application: exit status 1
```

This is the result of `clang --version`:

```
clang version 12.0.0
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You don’t say what operating system you are building from

Comment: @andy.xyz building from windows

Comment: Did you install the toolchain and set CC for the Linux architecture? https://docs.fyne.io/started/cross-compiling

If this seems confusing you could use fyne-cross that does it all for you inside containers instead.